# Javascript Push table rows to array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script that is generating a string of table rows and returning it back via an AJAX call. This string contains all the content between the `tbody` tags (`<tr>1</tr><tr>2</tr>`).

This data is passed back with the AJAX call so that I have access to it in my success function.

**PHP:**

```
$outputArray = Array();
$recordCount = 0;
$i = 0;

// Loop over our data
foreach($objData->data as $r){

  $outputArray[$i++] = '<tr data-qid="'.$r->identifierQID.'" class="primaryValue ' . searchMarkup($markupData, $r->identifierQID) . '">';

    // Loop over our fields
    foreach($r as $key => $value){

      // Vars
      $fieldID = str_replace('_', '', $key);

      // Don't include our identifier columns
      if(!in_array($fieldID, $ignore)){
        $outputArray[$i++] = '<td data-tableexport-display="always" class="small' . ($exportFields ? (in_array($fieldID, $exportFields) ? ' hidden' : '') : '') . '">' . formatFieldData($fieldID, $value) . '</td>';
      }

    }

    // Notes always come last
    $outputArray[$i++] = '<td data-tableexport-display="always" class="notesTD allowContext hidden"></td>';

  $outputArray[$i++] = '</tr>';
  $recordCount++;

}

// Join our rows array and return it
$end = microtime(true);
$timer = number_format($end - $start, 2);
return array(join("",$outputArray), $recordCount, $timer);`
```

I am trying to use this data with a plugin called `clusterize` which is used to handle large amounts of data in the DOM. It requires that each row be its own value in an array.

Example: `var data = ['<tr>…</tr>', '<tr>…</tr>', …];`

My issue is that my output is returned as a concatenated string containing all rows.

**My Question:**

How could I go about getting each `TR` as its own value in an array that I can supply back to my success function? Would it be best to do this on the PHP side or some how explode the final string into an array using javascript?

Comment: why join the array in php at the end? it seems like if you just didnt do that the problem is solved

Comment: @aw04 - Every line is an array value. The `tr`, `td` etc. It's a way to concatenate the string together without having to store it all as a single variable. If i remove that, i get an array with a key/value for every row/cell etc instead of one per row.

Comment: got it, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Return each row as you need it from the server to simplify and avoid useless work (ie join then later split). Here's an (untested) example:

```
$outputArray = Array();

foreach($objData->data as $r){
  $row = '<tr data-qid="'.$r->identifierQID.'" class="primaryValue ' . searchMarkup($markupData, $r->identifierQID) . '">';

  foreach($r as $key => $value){
    $fieldID = str_replace('_', '', $key);

    if(!in_array($fieldID, $ignore)){
      $row .= '<td data-tableexport-display="always" class="small' . ($exportFields ? (in_array($fieldID, $exportFields) ? ' hidden' : '') : '') . '">' . formatFieldData($fieldID, $value) . '</td>';
    }
  }

  $row .= '<td data-tableexport-display="always" class="notesTD allowContext hidden"></td>';
  $row .= '</tr>';

  $outputArray[] = $row;
}

$end = microtime(true);
$timer = number_format($end - $start, 2);

return array($outputArray, count($outputArray), $timer);
```